# separable polynomial $ \bmod p$ (definition)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Given a polynomial $ f(x) \in K[x]$, where $K$ is a number field, we say that $f$ is **separable**  if all its roots are distinct in an algebraic closure of $K$.

> Question: What does it mean a polynomial be separable $\bmod p$, where $p$ is a rational prime, or more generally separable $\bmod \mathfrak p $ where $\mathfrak p$ is a prime ideal, lets say in $\mathfrak O_K$ ?

If it is possible to give a concrete example, so I could understand it better.

Thank you in advance.

P.S The only reason that I put $K$ be a number field, is that basically interested in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that the polynomial is a separable polynomial when considered over $\mathbb{Z}/p \mathbb{Z}$ or more generally $\mathfrak{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$.

For example the polynomial $X^2 + 1$ is separable over the rationals, yet not separable modulo $2$, as modulo $2$ one has $X^2+1 = (X+1)^2$ modulo $2$.

Comment: I don't understand what will be the algebraic closure $ mod 2 $, although as I understood it is not necesarrily to determined it explicity, since whatever it is the only root of thr polynomial will be $ -1=1 mod 2$ with multiplicity 2. Right...?

Comment: It will be the algebraic closure of the field with two elements. However, usually one tests for separability differently.

Comment: Namelt, the fields in question are finite and thus perfect. Whence the only way a polynomial might be not separable is when there is the same irreducible factor multiple times.

Comment: you mean by taken the formal derivitive of the polynomial...?

Comment: Yes. Computationally the best way often is compute $f'$ and $\gcd(f,f')$ (Of course always over the correct field.)

Comment: Thank you very much for you time and the detailed explanation !